# android findViewById gets null instead of concret instance

Tags: android, callback, null, widget

I've got a problem. Since I am a newbie to develop Android apps, I suppose that I did not get all the concepts right.

The problem is:
In my dialog, after entering all the information and pushing the "Ok" button, I would like to get what I just entered into the `TextEdit` field. But when I try to 
get that `EditText` on `okButton.onClickListener` through `findViewById(R.id.myTextEditId)` I got `Null` instead of instance.

Here is some code:

Dialog's XML (part where I define EditText) :

```
    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:maxLines="3"
    android:hint="@string/add_new_note_hint">

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

Here is the code, where NPE accours:

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
View dialogView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.add_note_dialog,null);

dialogBuilder.setTitle(R.string.add_dialog_title)
.setPositiveButton(R.string.add_dialog_pos_but, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1); //this is where I get null instead of real instance.
    }
    })
```

Why am I getting this and what is the right way (best practice) to process widget's data in some callback method ? (how to fix)

Thank you very much, for your time on my issue!

Comment: what layout is editText1 in?

Comment: it is in a LinearLayout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `findViewById` searches the current view hierarchy. If you call this from your `Activity`, then it searches in your current activity's view hierarchy whereas you actually want to search your dialog's:

```
EditText et = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```

You'll probably need to make `dialogView` `final` as well.

Answer (score 4):

dialogView.findViewById will solve this